# Return result when count is below given value in spring mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am relatively new to mongodb and spring data.

I am looking for a way to perform operation below in thread-safe manner. In implementation below, it is possible that result set will exceed 1000 after if statement is executed and just before result is queried.

How do I perform such operation atomically?

```
if (mongoTemplate.count(myQuery, Document.class) > 1000) {
    throw new ResultSetTooLargeException()
}

return mongoTemplate.find(myQuery, Document::class.java)
```

Comment: Not possible. Once you run the query, it cannot be stoped

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it atomically but you can use `limit` which reduces it.

```java
return mongoTemplate.find(myQuery.limit(1000), Document::class.java)
```